# spring webflow: check attribute value and execute action

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I've two flows. From the first flow I'm passing a value to the second flow. I want to validate the value and if null then call an action. I tried with:

```
<input name="houseNumber" />    
<evaluate expression = "houseNumber != null ? createHouse : deleteHouse" />
```

Where createHouse is an action. But it's not calling.  Also tried like the below code. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the below code?

```
<input name="houseId" type="int" />
<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="houseId!= null" />
    <transition on="yes" to="loadHouse" />
    <transition on="no" to="emptyHouse" />
</on-start>
```

How can I call an action based on the input value

Answer (score 0):

I found a way and thought it would be helpful for beginners if I share it here.

Flow 1

```
<subflow-state id="home" subflow="flow2">
        <input name="homeId" value="requestParameters.homeId"/>
</subflow-state>
```

Flow 2

Create a decision-state and call it from an action state. You can call the action-state using 'start-state'

```
    <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
          start-state="start">

    <input name="homeId" type="int" />

    <action-state id="start" >
          <evaluate expression="controller.doSomething()"
          <transition on="success" to="makeDecision" />
    </action-state>

    <decision-state id="makeDecision">
            <if test="homeId== null" then="loadHome" else="emptyHome" />
    </decision-state>

    <action-state id="loadHome" >
            <evaluate expression="controller.method1()" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="emptyHome" >
             <evaluate expression="controller.method2()" />
     </action-state>
```